# Jasper Report with sub reports outside detail or multiple details

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to create a Report with 4 sections.
For this i saw the option of one report and other 3 sub reports.

the thing is that none of this sections are related so, i can't put the sub reports in the same detail band.

What are the options? create multiple detail brand with one sub report each? or put the subreports in the footers?

Is there an other way to do this without the sub reports?? if i can achieve this one just one .jrxml i would like to learn it.

I am using iReports 5.0.0 and jsf 2.0 to fill the data.

Regards.

example:

```
--------section 1---------
+----------+------+ -----
| title    | count|     |
+----------+------+     |
| ejample  | 150  |     |
| ejample  | 15   |     detail 
| ejample  | 10   |     |   
| ejample  | 1250 |     |   
| ejample  | 150  |     | 
+----------+------+ -----
--------section 2---------
+----------+------+ -----
| country  | %    |     |
+----------+------+     |
| ejample  | 150  |     |
| ejample  | 15   |     detail 
| ejample  | 10   |     |   
| ejample  | 1250 |     |   
| ejample  | 150  |     | 
+----------+------+ -----
--------section 3---------
   etc
```

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to use subreports each section. This way you dont have to mess up with one big jrxml if you want to modify something in one section. You can put the 4 subreports in the default detail band of your report.

Answer (score 0):

Add 4 detail bands - for each section a detail band. This because Sub Reports have a dynamic height, but the report element itself has a fixed height. In order to not have overlaying output put each subreport into a single band. detail bands grow with the size of the content.

depending on the complexity of the output you might want to consider to use sub datasets in the main report and arrange the display with the list or table element.

Comment: so, in the first detail its iterate over a list of items and then it pass to the next detail bands?

Comment: have 4 sub data sets, 4 detail bands and put in each detail band a list element using one of the datasets > this will allow you to have 4 independent sections in a single report. your main report you either set the query something similar to `select 1 from dual` to not get into the *no data* case.

Comment: thinking of it.. you'd better create a single *fake* group with e.g. 4 group header bands and set the report configuration for *when no data* to *all sections no detail*.